# JQuery Autocomplete loading data from model in aspx page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-ui

I am trying to

`1)` create a JQuery AutoComplete box that is populated from an aspx method, and

`2)`once I get the results, I wish to populate these results inside a list.

At the moment I am trying to do step one however without my success.

My code is as follows:-

ASPX

```
  <script>
  $(function () {

      $("#persons").autocomplete({
          //source: availableTags
          source: function (request, response) {
              var term = request.term;
              var personArray = new Array();

              $.post('JQAutoComplete.aspx/FetchPersonList', { personName: term }, function (persons) {
                  personArray = persons;
                  alert('PersonArray' - personArray);
                  alert('Persons' - persons);
                  response(personArray);
              });
          }
      });
  });
```

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="persons">Persons: </label>
  <input id="persons" />
</div>


</body>
```

and my aspx.cs is as follows :-

```
        public JsonResult FetchPersonList(string personName)
    {
        var persons = ctx.GetDataFromXML(false, 0);
        return (persons) as JsonResult;
    }
```

********************UPDATE ASPX.CS************************************
ok so I changed the method to this:-

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static List<Person> FetchPersonList()
    {
        //var persons = this.HouseService.SelectByName(houseName).Select(e => new String(e.Name.ToCharArray())).ToArray();
        var persons = ctx.GetDataFromXML(false, 0);

        return (List<Person>) persons;
    }
```

but I am still not getting through the method!

---

However the code is not hitting this method at all.

How can I get this list?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Try to set minLength for autocomplete and also "cache=false" for the ajax request

Comment: Have you decorated your method with [WebMethod] at server side? This could be the possible reason as well

Comment: the method should be static and also decorted with [WebMethod] attribute.

Comment: Have a look at this.. [ASP.Net Page Methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: is it MVC ? or asp.net Webforms ?, because you are returning JSONResult. so i asked

Comment: @ravi as of his question it is asp.net webforms

Comment: @Devjosh i know. but JSONResult is for asp.net MVC

Comment: @ravi oh i did not notice the return type

Comment: Ok Guys I was returning JSON since normally I use MVC for my projects and have not used aspx for some time.  So that is why I was returning JSON.  Does the request need to be a webservice?  Cannot it be a plain .aspx page?

Comment: @Johann it can be a method on your aspx page code behind(PageMethode), which is also decorated with [WebMethod] attribute but it should be static in order to be called.

Comment: @Devjosh I updated the answer, however I am still not getting through the breakpoint of the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem.

I changed my JQuery to the following and its calling the method now :-

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    SearchText();
});
function SearchText() {
    $("#persons").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "JQAutoComplete2.aspx/FetchPersons",
                data: "{'name':'" + document.getElementById('persons').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and my ASPX.CS looks like this :-

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static List<Person> FetchPersons(string name)
    {
        var persons = ctx.GetDataFromXML(false, 0);

        return (List<Person>)persons;

    }
```